# SD Card Micro SDHC "You don't currently have permission to access this folder"

Tags: windows-10, permissions, sd-card, micro-sd-card, windows-10-pro

I'm running on Windows 10 Pro, and every time I try to open my SD card it says "You don't currently have permission to access this folder. Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder." When I hit Continue it says "You have been denied access to this folder. To gain access to this folder you will need to use the security tab." I've used multiple methods to show the security tab and I can see it on normal folders, but when I go to Properties on SD cards there is no security tab. Same thing on the default admin account. Please help.

Comment: try to access the SD card in another PC or your phone(if it is microSD)

Comment: It works on other pcs but I NEED it on my pc, and my phone doesnt have an SD card slot.